# Gps delayed location

Tags: android, gps, location

Currently I'm doing a delayed send to server gps location. The location (lat and long) needs to be send every 3 minutes, right now for testing purpose it's set to be send every 20 seconds and I'm Logging the coordinates just to validate the output. The problem here is that when I'm **geo fixing** the location in the emulator (I don't have a device to test) the logger class prints all of my latest fixed locations and not only the last one. The handler with the postDelayed works, this is my class.

This code is from @kyogs.

```
public class LocalizadorGps extends Service {
    private LocationManager mlocmag;
    LocationListener mloclist;
    private  long UPDATE_INTERVAL;
    private double latn,longn;
    public Location loc;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mlocmag = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mloclist = new MyLocationList();

        loc = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (loc == null) {
            loc = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

        updateServer(loc);
        mlocmag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000, 1000,mloclist);


    }

    public void updateServer(final Location loc) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (loc != null) {
                    final double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    final double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    Log.v("COORDINATES", Double.toString(latitude) + " " + Double.toString(longitude));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Location not avilable");
                }

                handler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mlocmag.removeUpdates(mloclist);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        return super.stopService(name);
    }

    public class MyLocationList implements LocationListener {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateServer(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

    }
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
geo fix 44.41 56.75
```

And the output is:

```
06-27 04:03:55.736  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 56.75 44.409998333333334
```

Then I fix one more location:

```
geo fix 44.44 80.33
```

And the output is:

```
06-27 04:04:15.756  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 56.75 44.409998333333334
06-27 04:04:19.725  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 80.32999833333334 44.43999833333334
```

***It repeats the previously fixed location and the new one.*** The desired behavior is just the last location.

And the last one:

```
geo fix 44.44 33.67
```

the output:

```
06-27 04:04:35.767  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 56.75 44.409998333333334
06-27 04:04:39.686  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 33.669999999999995 44.43999833333334
06-27 04:04:39.736  13743-13743/com.example.testingui          
V/COORDINATES: 80.32999833333334 44.43999833333334
```

It repeats the three last fixed positions. (look at the time of the output). and once again the desired behavior is just the last location fixed.

**note:** I tested this with a Timer instead of a handler and i'm having the same result!

So my question here, is:

Am I doing something terribly wrong? I can't find the problem :(.

Comment: Just curious that why are you using `final` keyword with the variables for the Location in UpdateServer() function?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually closing the thread. Have you tried not spinning up a new Runnable each time?

Comment: So I wasn't trying that. I added **handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);** after the Runnable ends, but it seems not to be working. I'm getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're queuing up the same Runnable twice via two `handler.postDelayed` calls, so the second one queued from within the Runnable.run() is echoing same output from the first execution of the same Runnable.

This code:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (loc != null) {
                final double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                Log.v("COORDINATES", Double.toString(latitude) + " " + Double.toString(longitude));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Location not avilable");
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);
```

...should be changed to:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (loc != null) {
                final double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                Log.v("COORDINATES", Double.toString(latitude) + " " + Double.toString(longitude));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Location not avilable");
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 20000);
```